# Report Type: Opportunity with Orders with Products with Opportunity Team Members

Tags: reporting

Is this report type possible to create?

'Opportunity with Orders with Products with Opportunity Team Members'

From my understanding, it is not possible due to the objects not being hierarchal. Additionally, I have tried creating a Joined Report for this using 'Opportunities with Orders with Products' report type for Block 1 and 'Opportunities with Opportunity Team Members' for Block 2, but since we are filtering the records based on Product fields, this is returning more results than expected.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As defined in your requirements, you are attempting to report on three sibling child relationships. This is not supported for >1 child relationship

- Opportunities with Orders
- Opportunities with Products (i.e. OpportunityLineItems)
- Opportunities with Team Members

If the report only needs to show the specific children for one of those child relationships (sounds like Products) and merely filter on the presence/absence of the other two child relationships (with Orders, with OpportunityTeamMembers), then you could:

- Use Flows or triggers or DLRS to rollup a count of Orders on Opportunity
- Use Flows or triggers or DLRS to rollup a count of Team Members on Opportunity